# Java: Get all possible matches of RegExp / top-level backtracking

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a way to get all possible matches of a regular expression. **In other words**, I want to backtrack *after* the results are returned. Sorry if there is a technical term for this that I don't know.

Example:

```
Regular expression: "^(.+) - (.+)$"
Input: "A - B - C"
```

This should yield both the match ["A - B", "C"] and the match ["A", "B - C"].

Can java.util.regex do this and/or is there a library?

Comment: Regex's usually have rules which define which match is correct. Normally, regex matches are greedy, in that the largest possible match is the accepted one. It is possible to change this in the regex.

Comment: @NomadMaker Yes, I know. I want all solutions though, not just the greedy/non-greedy one.

Comment: This isn't possible with a single regex. You have to look at the strict definition of java regex.

Comment: It is definitely possible when someone implements this. I'm asking whether this has been done. Strikes me as a thing others may want too.

Comment: My suggestion: Use something like `(?<=^| - ).+?(?= - |$)` to separate out all the bits in between the dashes, then reconstruct all the possible combinations using a loop.  As others have said, doing it all in regex is definitely not the way to go, even if it might be possible with some crazy pattern.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong Thanks but that looks complicated... I think you guys are slightly misunderstanding, I am asking for a modified regexp engine that takes the unmodified regexp and puts it through its paces (returns all possible matches as described). Such an engine can definitely be made, the question is just if it has been made.

Comment: Most regex engines use fairly standard meanings for each symbol.  What you're describing wouldn't really be a *regex* engine.  I suppose you could define some new "Cruddie's Searching Engine," but to answer your question directly, no, this does not exist AFAIK.

Comment: Update to my first suggestion: Ditch the regex and use [`String#split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) instead.  I'm kinda embarrassed I even suggested the regex, don't use it.

Comment: In this case, I could use split, sure, but I'm asking about the general case. Thanks